# During Calling a servlet from another Servlet that contains session

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have 3 Servlets :

- Servlet1 - is used to create a session by :  `session = request.getSession(true)`
- Servlet2 - is used to display content of Servlet1
- Servlet3 is used to call Servlet2 by :HttpURLConnection connectionx = (HttpURLConnection) url
                                  .openConnection(); to get the result as :

---

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(((HttpURLConnection)
    (new URL(the_url)).openConnection()).getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

The problem is that : I found it when I Run Servlet1 to create the session
then I run Servlet 3 to call Servlet2 ...> I got that 'servlet 2'  Can not read from the created session..

But if I run Servlet2 directly from Browser I got a session.

What is the problem  with Servlet2
and how can I solve it ?!

Comment: That is one convoluted code line.  Try breaking it down into smaller parts for ease of understanding and checking, if nothing else.

Comment: You also need to clarify what you mean by calling each servlet.  How are you calling them?  Are the servlets invoking each other via server-side forwards or includes?  Or is the client calling each one individually?

Comment: no
just Servlet1  run manually on explorer..
the I run Servlet3 manually on explorer ...
so Servlet3 calls HttpRequest of Servlet2 ,, but Servlet2 can not see the session which was created by Servlet1... :(

Comment: Stop using `<pre>` for code!  To use code formatting, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Comment: @Maria are you using any session attributes to keep the datas?

Comment: yes I used a ShopingBag as an attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed passing JSESSIONID cookie when you call servlet 2 from servlet 3 using your HttpClient.

Comment: I think in servlet 3 you have to use request to get cookie named JSESSIONID and get the cookie value. You also need to find a way to send cookie from your http client.  I recommend using Apache HttpClient.

Comment: but the problem may be the cookies is not allowed at some client sides !?!?

Comment: I don't know exactly what is the purpose of calling servlet 2 from servlet 3 using url connection. I think something is not good design here since all 3 servlets are in the same servlet context so the calling seems not necessary.

Comment: It is better if you create another question asking for a solution or design for your purpose.

Comment: Because Servlet 2 return Some data from Database, and in Servlet 3 we need the data from Servlet2 , and then we need some calculation and formatting ! that was the purpose